# DB2 TSM Archivelog backups missing

Tags: backup, db2, ibm-tsm

New to DB2 on AIX currently running V9.7

Using TSM to backup the database with the command:

```
db2 backup db (db name here) online use tsm include logs
```

When I run the backup it finishes without error.

Using `db2adutl query`, I see the FULL DATABASE BACKUP information but I see nothing under LOG ARCHIVE:

```
Retrieving FULL DATABASE BACKUP information.

    1 Time: 20150305104339  Oldest log: S0000664.LOG  DB Partition Number: 0    Sessions: 2
    2 Time: 20150305100030  Oldest log: S0000662.LOG  DB Partition Number: 0    Sessions: 2
    3 Time: 20150305073135  Oldest log: S0000660.LOG  DB Partition Number: 0    Sessions: 2

Retrieving LOG ARCHIVE information.

  No LOG ARCHIVE images found for (db name here)
```

I have the following db archive parms set:

```
 (LOGARCHMETH1) = TSM

(LOGARCHCOMPR1) = OFF

  (LOGARCHOPT1) =

(TSM_MGMTCLASS) =

 (TSM_NODENAME) =

    (TSM_OWNER) =

 (TSM_PASSWORD) =
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have any logs actually been archived? You'd see records to that effect in `db2diag.log`. The `include logs` option makes the logs generated during the backup a part of the backup image itself, they don't count as "archived logs".

Comment: I don't see anything in the db2diag.log referring to archive logs.  I did notice that  Log retain for recovery status                          = NO
 User exit for logging status                            = YES   Could this be part of the issue?

Comment: There's no issue, since, as you say, no logs have been archived.

Comment: I changed:    db2 update db cfg for formsdev using LOGARCHMETH1 DISK:/db2/formsdev/data1/archivelog and then did
   db2 archive log for database FORMSDEV and I now have archived logs.  How do it get them to TSM and have db2adutl see them?

Comment: When `LOGARCHMETH?` is set to TSM, logs will be archived to TSM and become visible to `db2adutl`, provided TSM has been configured properly. Why do you want to archive them to disk then manually move them to TSM?

Comment: I don't.   I just wanted to see logs archived in the db2diag.log. Is it possible that I need to cold backup to level set the process after i change LOGARCHMETH1 back to TSM?

Comment: No you don't. After you set it to TSM, do the `archive log` command again and it should move to TSM (or fail; in either case you'll see a record in `db2diag.log`).